# If there's no majority candidate, does the incumbent or newly elected Congress choose the President and Vice President?

Tags: united-states

If no candidates get a majority in the U.S. electoral college, are the President and Vice President chosen by the incumbent Congress or the ones just elected?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The newly elected Congress does all of the work in electing a new President.**

Under the 20th Amendment, the newly elected Congress takes office on January 3. Then three days later, on January 6, [3 USC § 15: Counting electoral votes in Congress,](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/15) requires the new Congress to meet in Joint Session to count the electoral votes.

If this session does not produce a President or Vice President, there is what is called a [contingent election.](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R40504.pdf) In a contingent election the House begins immediately to choose a President from among the *top three* electoral college vote getters, while the Senate chooses a Vice President from among the *top two* electoral college vote getters. Both Houses use majority rule. The House votes by state, so a majority is 26, while the Senators vote individually, so a majority is 51.

If the House does not pick a President by Inauguration Day, January 20th, the Vice President serves until a President is picked. If neither a President nor a VP has been picked by the 20th, the [Presidential Succession Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Succession_Act) applies, and the Speaker of the House, President *pro tempore* or a cabinet officer serves as Acting President.

**It wasn't always done this way:**

The 20th Amendment was passed in 1933 to take control over elections away from the *lame duck* Congress. *Before the 20th A was adopted,* the terms for P, VP *and* Congress *all* ended on Inauguration day, March 4. That meant the lame duck Congress *had* to deal with electoral matters. By giving Congress and the P/VP different expiration dates, the Amendment meant new Congress *could* deal with the election. Setting the election counting date after the new Congress was seated (on January 6), meant *only* the new Congress could.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: if the new Senate tied, the “old” (current) VP still breaks the tie.

Comment: @Damila Good point! This happens because the terms for the P & VP don't end until Inauguration Day, January 20th, while the new Congress takes office on January 3. Before the 20th Amendment was passed in 1933, the P, VP and Congress all served until March 4, so the electoral duties *had* to be  handled by the "lame duck" Congress.

Comment: Actually it is not clear if the VP would get to break the tie. The 12th says a majority if the Senators so maybe with a tie they have to see if they can come up with a deal. I wonder if that has ever been discussed. VP clearly breaks other ties (Article 1) but the wording there makes it reasonably clear he is not a Senator.

Comment: @Damila I think you are right. Article I says the VP "shall have no Vote, *unless they be equally divided.*" But as you point out, the 12th says "a *majority of the whole number* shall be necessary to a choice," which means a tie means no "choice."

Comment: It would be wild. EC ties, or some state can’t get their votes in or something (unlikely, but this is 2020!) Senate is 50-50 (possible). Does Pence get to vote for himself? This after Harris/Duckworth/Warren/? voted for herself. As a Senator can one of the latter object (probably someone else would anyway). And you thought 2000 would be taught in Election Law electives in law school for years to come. :)

Comment: @Damila Now imagine a Senator gets COVID the week before the inauguration and can't attend the voting. Could be a wild few months.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim Right? Or there is an outbreak affecting many Senators and an argument ensures of whether or not they can hold the whole thing remotely. But it's 50-50 so there is not actually a Majority leader and they have to work out a cooperative agreement.

Comment: One thing that irks me about the twelfth amendment is that it limited the choices to the top three EC vote-getters.  So if the _current_ Congress were to choose, Biden would be president and Pence would be VP.

Comment: Also, despite what The Don seems to assume, if January 20, 2021 noon comes along and no one has been elected, he does not get to just stay. (see 20th Amendment, Section 3 and Presidential Succession Act of 1947). If all else stays as expected, we would get President Pelosi for at least a while.

Comment: @WGroleau I understand your general point, but your assumption of the result is not correct. Current House by state by party is 26-23-1 for the GOP. House selection of POTUS is not one Rep-one vote, it is by state, one state-one vote. One would have to look closely to see if there are any delegations that are close enough that if one or two  GOP reps voted for Biden instead it could flip.

Comment: @Damila Where'd you get the list of house delgation composition?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim https://www.270towin.com/news/2018/11/15/2018-midterms-partisan-control-of-the-us-house-by-state_714.html  See update at top. Maybe there have been one or two other changes? (I did not personally count: I took their word for it.)

Comment: I didn't see in the amendment how a state determines it's single vote.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It's not in the Amendment. It's based on precedent from the 1825 election. There's a nice discussion of voting rules, and how they might be changed, in the CRS report on contingent elections here: https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R40504.pdf#page=15

Comment: If the VP vote was tied, it would almost certainly go to the SCOTUS whether the outgoing VP gets a vote or not.  It's not sufficiently clear that they don't, though it certainly seems that way.

Comment: And @Damila - FL has a 14-13 R majority, and WI has a 5-3 R majority.  MI has 7-6-1 D majority, but that 1 is Justin Amash (MI 3rd CD) whose seat is fairly likely to return to R hands ("Lean Republican").  No other state is particularly likely to switch at least based on numbers - not looking at individual races, of course.  It seems likely though that in an environment where Trump got 269 EVs, that FL, WI, and MI would not swing more D than they already did last year.

Comment: I knew the house was by state but I did not realize the distribution was that way.  So if enough people in the right states went Libertarian, we'd probably get Trump again.  But at least it would send a message.

Comment: @Joe, good points. I actually was wondering aloud if there are any states where it is close, as you listed, where one of the GOP members is liable to vote for Biden anyway. A House Mitt Romney as it were. Maybe all of those people were already defeated in a primary for being a "RINO" or in 2018 general because they were in a purple district.

Comment: @Damila Unfortunately house reps tend to be much more partisan than senators - they're representing a much smaller bit so it's much easier to be an extremist, not many states that are even remotely purple can tolerate Kris Kobach types (see: Kansas, after all) at the state level.   Look at how many republicans voted for impeachment, after all.